# Superfish menu spacing is off

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a bit of a spacing problem with a superfish drop down menu. You can see the issue here: 
http://screencast.com/t/V8g5ZrDXDZV

You can see it live here: http://goo.gl/kzImjK

Basically all of the submenu items are floated left with a 50% width. I need to remove that big space and basically have the items get right underneath the sub menu items.

Comment: Since you are using WP, why not changing the order of your menu items under WP-Admin --> Appearance --> Menu, and place Dining & Nightlife further down the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regarding your big space problem:

Ok, based on our exchange, and using jQuery, you could:

1. Append all your secondary submenu li items to the primary submenu, right after the primary submenu li item that used to contain them.

   2. Add a css class to said items to be able to target them (if need be).
2. Add a `menu-changed` class to your `#navigation` div, and add a custom set of styles to it (so that they only work if the JS did).

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navigation li ul li ul").each(function() {
        $(this).children("li").each(function() {
            $(this)
                .addClass("was-submenu-item")
                .insertAfter($(this).closest("ul").parent());
        });
        $(this).closest("li").removeClass("menu-item-has-children");
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $("#navigation").addClass("menu-changed");
    console.log($(".was-submenu-item"));
});
```

### CSS:

```
#navigation .was-submenu-item a {
    /* some styles here */
}
#navigation.menu-changed ul li {
    /* some styles here */
}
```

### Fiddle:

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/1whatmjr/) for reference.

### Regarding your alignment problem:

Look for the following style selector inside your theme's `main.css` style sheet: `#navigation li ul li ul li a`, and get rid of the margin and customize the padding, like so:

```
#navigation li ul li ul li a {
    padding: 5px 4px;
    /* margin-left: 20px; */
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there another way to fix the space without moving the menu around? I tried using display:inline-block without a float and that didn't seem to work either. My only other thing would be something like jQuery Masonry.

Comment: You are welcome! I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks. That's how it was before actually. But they want these sub menus open all the time . I'm thinking I may have to use a little JS for this one.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see how you could pull that off with JS, since your secondary submenus will be hidden (`display:none`). Let me give it a little bit more thought...

Comment: Just updated my answer. It still requires a little bit of CSS adjusting, but it works.